# Hibernate get parent child lazy loading with addtional check

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables `Company` and `Employees`, one-to-many mapping. Company table contains composite primary key.

I want to search from company table based on primary id but want to put an additional check on the child table.

I want to load only a particular type of employees which I will get in the request. How it can be done in `Sprongboot` `JPA` with `findById("id")`;

```
class Company{
    @Id
    private String companyId;
    @Id
    private String stateId;
    private String company Name;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Employees.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<Employees> empList;
}

class Employees{
    @Id
    private String id;
    //foreign key
    private String companyId;
    //foreign key
    private String stateId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "companyId", referencedColumnName = "companyId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true),
            @JoinColumn(name = "stateId", referencedColumnName = "stateId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true) })
    private Company company;
    private int salary;
    private String type;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Filter, which is an alternative of `@Where` where you can set dynamic value.

Here is the sample

```
@FilterDef(
        name = "employeeTypeFilter",
        parameters = @ParamDef(name = "type", type = "string")
)
@Filter(
        name = "employeeTypeFilter",
        condition = "type > : type"
)
public class Employees {

}
```

You can enable or disable filter from your code dynamically based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Where for fixed type

```
 @Where(clause = "type = 'anyEmployeeType'")
 private Set<Employees> empList;
```

For dynamically fetch you can query in Employees repository

```
List<Employees> findByTypeAndCompany(String type, Company company);
```

Comment: How dynamically set the value of it based on request type? can it be dynamic or hardcoded

Comment: Nope it's fixed as you say `particular type of employees`. If you need dynamic then you have query in Employees repository like `findByTypeAndCompany` to get all employee

Comment: I mean I will get the type of employee in the request and based on that I have to fetch the list.

Comment: Maybe lazy load child dynamically by condition not possible as far I know